# jQuery that POSTS, but not returning any values Python, Flask

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

Maybe I am getting all this wrong, but from what I've understood, if I have  a form on my HTML page that I can submit, by click button of a type-"submit", I can also do it by creating a jQuery function with

```
$("#formid").submit().
```

It does trigger "POST" on the server, but without passing any values. Here is the code for the function - I refer to "i", because that's how my star rating script generates my input type number.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("i").click(function () {

    $("form").submit();
    alert("nothing");
})
});
```

Here is the code for the form and  :

```
<form method="post" name="test" id="myform" action="{{ url_for('whatulike', page = page )}}">

<input type="number" name="{{ row[1] }}" id="some_id" class="rating"
data-icon-lib="fa" data-active-icon="fa-star" data-inactive-icon="fa-star-o"
{% for rating in user_rating  %}{% if rating[0]==row[1] %} value="{{ rating[1] }}"{% endif %}{% endfor %}data-empty-value="0" />
```

My page has 20 elements with star ratings, and after user rates multiple of them, I can submit using button, and send data to the server. I would like to send data without the need of a button. To be clear - after clicking a regular `<input type="submit" >` it all works well.

I am also adding the rating-input script ( that generates star rating ) since that might be interfering somehow.

```
! function(a) {
"use strict";

function b(a) {
    return "[data-value" + (a ? "=" + a : "") + "]"
}

function c(a, b, c) {
    var d = c.activeIcon,
        e = c.inactiveIcon;
    a.removeClass(b ? e : d).addClass(b ? d : e)
}

function d(b, c) {
    var d = a.extend({}, i, b.data(), c);
    return d.inline = "" === d.inline || d.inline, d.readonly = "" === d.readonly || d.readonly, d.clearable === !1 ? d.clearableLabel = "" : d.clearableLabel = d.clearable, d.clearable = "" === d.clearable || d.clearable, d
}

function e(b, c) {
    if (c.inline) var d = a('<span class="rating-input"></span>');
    else var d = a('<div class="rating-input"></div>');
    d.addClass(b.attr("class")), d.removeClass("rating");
    for (var e = c.min; e <= c.max; e++) d.append('<i class="' + c.iconLib + '" data-value="' + e + '"></i>');
    return c.clearable && !c.readonly && d.append("&nbsp;").append('<a class="' + f + '"><i class="' + c.iconLib + " " + c.clearableIcon + '"/>' + c.clearableLabel + "</a>"), d
}
var f = "rating-clear",
    g = "." + f,
    h = "hidden",
    i = {
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        "empty-value": 0,
        iconLib: "glyphicon",
        activeIcon: "glyphicon-star",
        inactiveIcon: "glyphicon-star-empty",
        clearable: !1,
        clearableIcon: "glyphicon-remove",
        inline: !1,
        readonly: !1
    },
    j = function(a, b) {
        var c = this.$input = a;
        this.options = d(c, b);
        var f = this.$el = e(c, this.options);
        c.addClass(h).before(f), c.attr("type", "hidden"), this.highlight(c.val())
    };
j.VERSION = "0.4.0", j.DEFAULTS = i, j.prototype = {
    clear: function() {
        this.setValue(this.options["empty-value"])
    },
    setValue: function(a) {
        this.highlight(a), this.updateInput(a)
    },
    highlight: function(a, d) {
        var e = this.options,
            f = this.$el;
        if (a >= this.options.min && a <= this.options.max) {
            var i = f.find(b(a));
            c(i.prevAll("i").andSelf(), !0, e), c(i.nextAll("i"), !1, e)
        } else c(f.find(b()), !1, e);
        d || (a && a != this.options["empty-value"] ? f.find(g).removeClass(h) : f.find(g).addClass(h))
    },
    updateInput: function(a) {
        var b = this.$input;
        b.val() != a && b.val(a).change()
    }
};
var k = a.fn.rating = function(c) {
    return this.filter("input[type=number]").each(function() {
        var d = a(this),
            e = "object" == typeof c && c || {},
            f = new j(d, e);
        f.options.readonly || f.$el.on("mouseenter", b(), function() {
            f.highlight(a(this).data("value"), !0)
        }).on("mouseleave", b(), function() {
            f.highlight(d.val(), !0)
        }).on("click", b(), function() {
            f.setValue(a(this).data("value"))
        form.submit()}).on("click", g, function() {
            f.clear()
        })
    })
};
k.Constructor = j, a(function() {
    a("input.rating[type=number]").each(function() {
        a(this).rating()
    })
})
}(jQuery);
```

I got it from https://github.com/javiertoledo/bootstrap-rating-input. I can see it has form.submit at the very bottom, when clicking star, in the console I get an error `bootstrap-rating-input.min.js:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing my approach - instead of using the form I've already created, I came up with a .post function for jQuery that does what I need it to do.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("i").click(function () {
        var values = $(this).attr("data-value")
        var name = $(this).closest("h4").find("input").attr("name")
        $.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "/whatulike/",
data: JSON.stringify([values,name]),
success: function (data) {
console.log(data.title);
console.log(data.article);
},
dataType: "json"
});
      })
})
```

Now I can recieve it in even better form than before using `requests.get_json()`